# Grouping columns in p:panelGrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 5 and I want to create something like this

```
-----------------------------
| HEADER                     |
-----------------------------
|       USER IMAGE           |
-----------------------------|
|    Key        |    Value   |
-----------------------------
|    Key        |    Value   |
-----------------------------
|    Key        |    Value   |
-----------------------------
```

So for what i have is

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:column colspan="2">User Profile</p:column>
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="User ID"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{fitbitAuthResponseMB.userProfile.userId}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I tried using `<p:row>` like this

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:column colspan="2">User Profile</p:column>
        </f:facet>

        <p:row>
           <p:column colspan="2">
               <h:graphicImage value=".."/>
           </p:column>
        </p:row>

        <p:row>
           <p:column>

               <h:outputText value="User ID"/>
           </p:column>
           <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{fitbitAuthResponseMB.userProfile.userId}"/>
           </p:column>
        </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

but it didn't work as i expected.

**What did my code do**

```
-----------------------------
| HEADER       | USER IMAGE  |
-----------------------------
|    Key        |    Value   |
-----------------------------
|    Key        |    Value   |
-----------------------------
|    Key        |
-----------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but it seems that if you want to use p:row, you have to define all rows and columns with p:row and p:column. So you can't use the attribute "columns" of p:panelGrid.
Try this:

```
<p:panelGrid >
    <f:facet name="header">
     <p:row>
        <p:column colspan="2">User Profile</p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>

    <p:row>
       <p:column colspan="2">
           <h:graphicImage value=".."/>
       </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row>
       <p:column>

           <h:outputText value="User ID"/>
       </p:column>
       <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{fitbitAuthResponseMB.userProfile.userId}"/>
       </p:column>
    </p:row></p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: how is that different than what i wrote ?

Comment: As i tell you have to define all rows and columns in your table with p:row and p:column (for example you have <p:panelGrid columns="2">, i write <p:panelGrid >. You doesn't user p:row in header section, instead i use it). Don't mix the approach with columns attribute and p:row tag.